# Android Studio Emulator W/AudioTrack Error

Tags: android, logcat

Everything was working fine with testing my app on the emulators in android studio, then all of a sudden i started getting

W/AudioTrack: AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client

Without making any changes to my program or the build, now i can no longer view any messages from my program, when i run my program on my phone however it runs as usual and logcat is able to provide all feedback.

To clarify, Logcat is no longer showing me any results from my app when running in the emulator other than the AudioTrack message, i have tried to create new emulators with no success. Logcat shows all information when connected to my phone, however as it is an API level too high (23) , i cannot test my programs full functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you select your app process in logcat
[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GH50U.png)